# Filter an array of 2D points in Matlab to fit a criteria

Tags: arrays, matlab, find

I have a list of x,y points like this

```
points = [[1,2];[2,5];[7,1]...[x,y]]
```

How can I filter the points array to only return the points that match a criteria

for example return all points with the  0 < x < 5 and 0 < y < 2.

I have this but it gives an error.

```
points(points(1,:) > 0 && points(1,:) < 5 , points(:,1) > 0 && points(:,1) < 2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In this specific case where the lower bound = 0, you could also use: `points(all(points-[5,2]<0,2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- You need to replace  `&&` by `&`. The difference is that `&&` is only for scalars, and does short-circuiting (i.e. `0 && x` works even if `x` is undefined).
- You should use `points(:,1)` and `points(:,2)` for the *x* and *y* columns respectively in the logical conditions.
- The indexing is also incorrect. The result of your logical conditions is a logical index that should be applied along the first dimension only (to select the desired rows), with `:` as index in the second dimension (to keep all columns):

  ```
  points(points(:,1) > 0 & points(:,1) < 5 & points(:,2) > 0 & points(:,2) < 2, :)
  ```
- As a side note, the inner brackets in the definition of `points` are not needed:

  ```
  points = [1,2; 2,5; 7,1];
  ```